# A Trivial Pursuit #17 (Science and Nature 3/4): Workaround

Tags: word, crosswords, anagram

<sub>This is part 17 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

Solve the clues and enter their answers into the grid below as a single chain, where the last letter of one clue is the first letter of the next, and the chain bends around the ends of the rows.

[image: Around-the-bend crossword grid]
<sub>*Solve on [Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/ycyc652j)*</sub>

> 1. Coarse (5)
> 2. Chapter (5)
> 3. Evergreen (3)
> 4. Vase (3)
> 5. Whinny (5)
> 6. Thy (4)
> 7. Lumber (4)
> 8. Pudding (7)
> 9. Ensemble (6)
> 10. Forecaster (7)
> 11. Educated (6)
> 12. That place (5)
> 13. Twist (5)
> 14. Bear (7)

Er, hang on – looking at those letter counts, something’s not quite right here. Fortunately, the letters in the shaded cells will anagram to a hospital department you might find useful if you struggle to solve this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The department is

> [OTIATRY](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/otiatry) (ear medicine).

The words to be entered in the grid

> Are all homophones of the clued answers thus we have the clued answers:
> 1. ROUGH
>  2. PHASE
>  3. YEW
>  4. URN
>  5. NEIGH
>  6. YOUR
>  7. WOOD
>  8. DESSERT
>  9. TROUPE
>  10. PROPHET
>  11. TAUGHT
>  12. THERE
>  13. WRING
>  14. GRIZZLY

leading to the entries

> 1. RUFF
>  2. FAZE
>  3. EWE
>  4. EARN
>  5. NAY
>  6. YAW
>  7. WOULD
>  8. DESERT
>  9. TROOP
>  10. PROFIT
>  11. TORT
>  12. THEIR
>  13. RING
>  14. GRISLY
>  [image: GRID]

so that the highlighted letters are

> RAOTITY

which anagrams to

> OTIATRY appropriately for a homophone puzzle.

Comment: Exactly right - all correct :) Funnily enough though, I had forgotten about the word you used in #11 (in my head there was only the one of the form .AU.), which now makes me feel I should have noticed this and made the clue 'Stretched' instead, to remove any ambiguity. No need to make any alterations to your answer, just a point of design feedback from me to me (!)